# Using Scala script in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

We are planning to using `Scala` on `Spark` to make computations. Just want to know what is the best way to execute `Scala` in `Spark` ; `Scala as Script` (or) `Scala as Application`. Is there any **advantage**/**disadvantage** between these 2 methods?

As mentioned [here](https://dataissexy.wordpress.com/2015/02/21/running-scala-scripts-in-spark/) it is possible to execute `Scala as Script`. I am trying to skip the compilation process using `sbt` so that I can use `Scala` as script just like we will use `Python`

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you mean by scala as script the scala REPL comes with spark (spark-shell) and scala application is the standlaone appliction packaged by `sbt` or `maven`.

- Use scala shell (`spark-shell`) to test your algoriothm/implementation . So it should be used as staging phase.
- When you have tested your implementation you should put it in a standalone application, package it and deliever a "fat jar" that could be submited by using `spark-submit`

Hope this is clear enough

Comment: I have updated my question. I just want to skip the manual compilation process using `sbt` ; so that I can execute `scala as script` similar to `Python`

Comment: That is the same thing mentioned in my answer. Most of the time you use some dependencies in your application so you need to package them within your application to launch it on a cluster.  for Scala scripts ,IMHO, could not be delivered in production environment